# Converting columns in SQLite database to cell values

Tags: python, sqlite

Let's say I have the following database structure:

| fruits | vegetables | grains |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | carrot | wheat |
| apple | broccoli | barley |
| watermelon | cabbage | malt |
| strawberry | tomato | semolina |

And I want it to be a bit easier to work with, transforming it into the following structure instead:

| name | type |
| --- | --- |
| banana | fruit |
| apple | fruit |
| broccoli | vegetable |
| barley | grain |
| tomato | vegatable |
| wheat | grain |

How would I go about writing a python program that could do this for me?

I found this solution to be workable - but maybe it's not as pythonic/readable as it should be:

```
import sqlite3

def transform():
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur2 = con.cursor()
    cur3 = con.cursor()
    data = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM table_1''')
    columns = []
    for column in data.description:
        columns.append(column[0])
    for columnx in columns:
        cur2.execute(f'''SELECT {columnx} FROM table_1''')
        content = cur2.fetchall()
        for word in content:
            word = str(word)
            word = word.strip("(),' ")
            if word != "None":
               cur3.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table_1_V2 (column1, column2) VALUES (?,?);''',(str(word),str(columnx)))
    con.commit()
```

Comment: I wrote a working program myself. See reply. Could be useful to others who want to solve a similar issue without getting too bogged down in code they will never work with again.

Comment: Didn't see that you answered your own question. I'll delete my comment. You should accept your answer if it's suitable for you. Consider editing it to generalise a bit. And use http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to provide future readers with a working schema and a table with data.

Comment: Thanks - will look into it.

Comment: Voting to reopen, since OP is the Answerer, so has code (ie shown effort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following program does the job - although it could probably be a bit more pythonic/readable:

```
import sqlite3

def transform():
    con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur2 = con.cursor()
    cur3 = con.cursor()
    data = cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM table_1''')
    columns = []
    for column in data.description:
        columns.append(column[0])
    for columnx in columns:
        cur2.execute(f'''SELECT {columnx} FROM table_1''')
        content = cur2.fetchall()
        for word in content:
            word = str(word)
            word = word.strip("(),' ")
            if word != "None":
               cur3.execute(f'''INSERT INTO table_1_V2 (column1, column2) VALUES (?,?);''',(str(word),str(columnx)))
    con.commit()
```

In the INSERT statement here, column1, column2 can be extended with however many columns you want to fill in your new table, and the values that are to be inserted in the new column are found at the end of the statement (word and columnx here). Note that you have to actually create the new table with the desired contents for this code to work.